# Importation of .csv on grass gis converts numeric data to string data

Tags: grass-gis, ogr, database, csv, import

When importing a csv file on grass7, the numeric data is converted into a data of type string.

My csv looks like this :

```
    id_core value
1   F1  83.0611472396 
2   F2  98.8584345936
3   F3  102.0621496367
4   F4  95.4304750175
...
```

The command I use is :
    `db.in.ogr dsn=my_file.csv output=my_table`

which displays the following message :

```
WARNING: Width for column field_1 set to 255 (was not specified by OGR),
         some strings may be truncated!
WARNING: Width for column id_core set to 255 (was not specified by OGR), some
         strings may be truncated!
WARNING: Width for column value set to 255 (was not specified by OGR), some
         strings may be truncated!
WARNING: 50 features without geometry
Imported table <my_table> with 50 rows
```

And `db.describe -c table=my_table` returns :

```
ncols: 3
nrows: 50
Column 1: field_1:TEXT:1000
Column 2: core:TEXT:1000
Column 3: stock:TEXT:1000
```

I tried to import the .csv without the header, or with only 2 decimal places on the values. I also tried to import an sqlite file (that I created with with libreoffice base) but the output is identical.

Does anyone has a suggestion for specifying that some fields are numeric?

Thanks

Léo

Answer (score 1):

Check out the first example here: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/db.in.ogr.html

> Limited type recognition can be done for Integer, Real, String, Date, Time and DateTime columns through a descriptive file with same name as the CSV file, but .csvt extension

Try to create a csvt file (with the same name as your csv file) according to the [OGR documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html).

Comment: Creating a csvt file containing : "Integer(3)","String(10)","Real(10.7)" worked.